# Print using Flash & Actionscript but without PrintJob

Tags: flash, printing, actionscript

I'm designing an interface for a touch-screen device using Flash and I want it to be able to print the stage on paper. But if I use PrintJobs, at some point I must either call the start() or the start2() function. The problem is, start() automatically shows the printer's dialog, which I don't want to see ; and start2(), which can control whether or not the dialog appears, only works on AIR runtime, not on simple SWF files. I would like it to work using only the SWF.

Is there something in PrintJob I'm missing ? Or is there another way to print from Flash that I might explore ?

The code I use so far is very common :

```
    var myPrintJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

    var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
    s.addChild(/* Some Bitmap object */);

    if (myPrintJob.start2(null, false)) {
        try {
            myPrintJob.addPage(s);
        } catch (error:Error) { 
            trace(error);
        } 
        myPrintJob.send();
    }
```

Thank you all !